# sonar login failure

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

i installed sonar on rhel 6.3 64 bit machine and integrated it with mysql database. Following is my sonar.properties file details:

```
#----- MySQL 5.x/6.x
# Comment the embedded database and uncomment the following line to use MySQL
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:mysql://10.217.14.40:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true

# Optional properties
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
sonar.host.url=http://10.217.14.40:9000/
```

also i created the sonar database, sonar user, and grant permissions by using the script provided in the sonar installation

```
CREATE DATABASE sonar CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE USER 'sonar' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar'; 
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar'; 
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now when i try to login to sonar i get "AUTHENTICATION FAILED" message please could somebody help me

Comment: The sonar credentials you created on MySQL is for Sonar to access MySQL

Answer (score 0):

The default built-in credentials for a first install of Sonar are "admin/admin".

Is it what you're using to log in?

Comment: Thanks for you input i could now login to sonar

Comment: But how do i login to mysql database named "sonar" from my sonar application

Comment: Hum, OK, I misunderstood your question. You're saying that you get this "authentication failed" message from the log, right? If so, can you update your post to add the part of the log where there's the authentication failed message?

Comment: actually you had understood me correctly initially i could not login to sonar but you suggested i could login using admin/admin but now i would like to know how do i connect to my Mysql database "sonar"

Comment: @user1670818 That's a second question unrelated to Sonar. I would recommend that you first accept this answer..... To login to the database you need a mysql client, from the commandline you could try "mysql -u sonar -psonar sonar"